# Python3 object method overwritten by dictionary key

Tags: python-3.x

I have an object that inherits from MutableMapping; it has

```
def __setitem__(self,key,value):
    self.__dict__[key]=value
```

Entries are named exactly the same as whatever comes back from os.listdir(), *minus* extension. A file spam.tgz creates an entry with the key "spam". "spam.png" uses the same key, but turns the value into a list: ["tgz","png",].

The object has methods like this:

```
def keys(self):
    return list(self.__dict__.keys())
```

The problem comes in when there is a file called "keys.tgz", for instance.  __setitem() creates an entry called "keys"--which overwrites the keys() method, shown above. Any method that happens to have the name of a file in the directory gets overwritten, making all kinds of trouble.

The problem doesn't arise with regular dictionaries, because essential methods like keys() can't be overwritten--they are read-only attributes. I can't make these methods read-only, because I can't control the names of files on disk, and I don't see how to work around the issue. I'm at a loss here. I'm preventing crashes in one directory where I control the filenames by renaming, but that's not a long-term solution.

Comment: "I can't control the names of files on disk".  You are using the wrong approach then, and your experience is telling you this.  You should probably be using a dictionary with string keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a workaround without abandoning the inheritance from MutableMapping. Once one does that, and replaces references to `self.__dict__` with references to an internal dictionary that's created in `__init__()`, everything works just fine.

In my case, I wrote a bunch of tests, created `self.items={}` and changed the references throughout the code, everything ran correctly, both for the tests and in actual practice.

However, the keys were *always* only strings, so it is unclear to me why a string key `self.__dict__["keys"]` overwrote the `self.__dict__.keys` method, whereas `self.items["keys"]` does not.